# How to validate db.collections.insertOne inputs on mongoose and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a problem. I am new to node.js and mongoDB (using mongoose). In MySQL when I have defined a table with required fields the database will refuse to accept input that don't conform to the model's rules. I have noticed that in mongoDB, at least, the way I have set it up, this is not the case.

I have defined the following model in `blog-schema.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
            type:String,
            required: true,
        },
        author: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        category: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
        },
    })

module.exports = mongoose.model('BlogPost', userSchema, 'blog');
```

In this, I set `required:true` for all fields apart from `date`. I then implemented this in `conn.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
, BlogPost = require('./schemata/blog-schema')
, db_config = require('./config')
, uri = 'mongodb://' + db_config.user + ":" + db_config.password + "@" + db_config.host + db_config.database;

 DataFunctions = function (){

    mongoose.connect(uri, db_config.opts);

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    this.connections = {};
    this.schemas = {};

    this.schemas.BlogPost = BlogPost;

    this.connections.db = mongoose.connection;
};

DataFunctions.prototype.insert = function(data = {}, callback = null) {
    var schema = this.schemas.BlogPost;

    this.connections.db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
    this.connections.db.once('open', function(dataStructure = schema) {
        this.items = data;


        if (callback != null) {
            dataStructure.collection.insertOne(this.items, callback);
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }
        else {
            dataStructure.collection.insertOne(this.items, function(err, docs)     {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
            mongoose.connection.close();
        }

    });

    mongoose.connection.close();
    }

    DataFunctions.prototype.retrieve = function(params = {}, columns = '', callback = null) {
    var schema = this.schemas.BlogPost;

    this.connections.db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error'));
    this.connections.db.once('open', function(dataStructure = schema) {

        if (callback != null) {
            dataStructure.find(params, columns, callback);
        }
        else {
            dataStructure.find(params, columns, function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });

        }
    });


}


module.exports = DataFunctions;
```

However, when I execute the insert function, it accepts it without error even when fields marked `required` are left blank. I would really appreciate any assistance in working out how to validate the data inserted into the mongoDB collection.

I am using mongoos version 5.3.6, and mongoDB version 4.0.3

Thank you.

**Edit**
Thanks to everyone who replied, based on some of the comments below I changed `dataStructure.collection.insertOne()` to `dataStructure.create()`, which appears to include validation.

Comment: show form where you are collecting data for a more complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add verification on submit as well or before submit. When the form has errors it is actually invalid so check if it is invalid before submitting..

Tbh you code seems a little verbose, complicated and confusin.. is there are reason you are doing it like this? For example you are using a mongoose schema but not actually submitting with the mongoose methods which is why none of your validations are occuring.. insertOne is not a mongoose method, and you aren't using your model to save the entry. it would be model.save(data)

also you can directly save without having to call the schema again, just declare a new variable.

```js
const post = new BlogPost(data); post.save().then(console.log).catch(console.log);


//also mongoose.connect already returns a promise

mongoose
  .connect(
    dbUrl,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("Connected"))
  .catch(error => console.log("Failed " + error));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added some JS verification for the form on submit. However, my problem is that my insert code appears to ignore the constraints specified in my model. It ignores `default:Date.now` as well. So I wondered if I could get it to use these constraints on top of verification. I don't know if this is possible as I am used to MySQL, where the database refuses inserts which do not conform to its model. If this is not possible then I apologize for my lack of knowledge of mongoDB and mongoose.

Comment: ok well what is your callback? and when you say Date.now is being ignored its because Date.now is not a function call.. Date.now(); is a function being called or new Date()

Comment: Tbh you code seems a little verbose, complicated and confusin.. is there are reason you are doing it like this? For example you are using a mongoose schema but not actually submitting with the mongoose methods which is why none of your validations are occuring.. insertOne is not a mongoose method, and you aren't using your model to save the entry. it would be model.save(data)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are passing empty string and that's why the validators are not flagging the entries as erroneous. Try passing null for the fields and check the behavaior.